# Eight-dimensional hypersurface related to $SU(3)$

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics

$\lambda_i$, $i=1,\ldots 8$ being Gell-Mann matrices, symmetric $d_{ijk}$ and antisymmetric $f_{ijk}$ $SU(3)$-tensors are defined through  the multiplication law (see https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103841153  Einstein summation convention over repeated indexes is assumed)
$$\lambda_i\lambda_j=\frac{2}{3}\delta_{ij}+(d_{ijk}+if_{ijk})\lambda_k.$$
When studying the Three-Higgs-doublet models, the following hypersurface appears in the 9-dimmensional $(r_0,r_1,\ldots ,r_8)$ space (see, for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.11472 ):
$$d_{ijk}r_ir_jr_k+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}r_0(r_0^2-3r_ir_i)=0.$$
Is anything known about such hypersurfaces in the mathematical literature?